# npm run dev: [webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'gensync'

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

After updating to bootstrap5, I find that I get this error when running mix via npm run dev.
I reverted back to my previous branch, but I'm still getting the same error when running npm run dev.

```
gmaddock@Wrecked:/var/www/dev-events$ npm run dev

> dev
> npm run development


> development
> mix

[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'gensync'
Require stack:
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/utils.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/package.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/FileCollection.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/tasks/ConcatenateFilesTask.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Combine.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /var/www/dev-events/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at _gensync (/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:12:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:23:22)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/utils.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/package.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/FileCollection.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/tasks/ConcatenateFilesTask.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Combine.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/var/www/dev-events/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: After some additional testing, I deleted package.json, deleted npm_modules, ran npm install, removed sass and sass-loader from devDependencies, ran npm install again and that got me back to being able to build dev.

Comment: Simply deleting `node_modules` fixed this for me.